Is there a math latex symbol of V enclosed in a circle and it's inverse?
I'm looking for the latex symbol of V enclosed in a circle, and for v written upside down also inside of a circle. I want them as an analog of \otimes to denote the wedge and cowedge product.
I've seen the former in print but not the latter. Also their 'big' versions, as in \bigotimes, if available, would come in handy

Welcome to TeX.SE!

Have a look at the stmaryrd package, it has \ovee and \owedge

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz: the link asks for one of the symbols, but not both and not their big versions so I think my question doesn't require editing.

Unicode provides \olessthan and \ogreaterthan. Rotating them and adjusting the spacing would probably give you what you want. Note that you need an opentype math font, such as newcm.

Maybe try something like this.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\Owedge}{\mathbin{\text{$\vcenter{\hbox{\textcircled{$\wedge$}}}$}}}

\begin{document}

$\Owedge$

\end{document}

